# Composite Dto update, best practice

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, encapsulation, dto

I have a composite Dto, where properties are primitive values or other Dtos (that occurred in many places).

Eg :

- PersonDto

  - Name
  - Surname
  - AddressDto

    - Street
    - Number
  - ContactDto

    - PhoneNo
    - EMail

In this example AddressDto and ContactDto are used in many other Dtos (not only PersonDto), so i am tempted to add some business logic to those Dtos.
In particular i would like to add update logic to those Dtos (eg: define an IUpdateable interface) to handle how the Dtos persist information.

In that way when i have to deal with a Dto i can check if it's a composite one, and in the case i know i can rely over IUpdateable children Dto contained in the parent Dto to get the "right update logic".

But i have the feeling this is not the correct way to proceede, Dtos (as name imply) shuld carry only information and no business logic. I don't like the idea to start attach logic to Dto also because then i am constrained to that specific logic (if i need a ContactDto with that exact structure but different update logic, my only option is to derive a new type..and this seems ugly)

That said, so far, i have indulged, in use interfaces over Dtos only if the interface is merely a "tag" that describe the "scope" of the Dto; and in that sense guarantee the fact that Dto will contain some properties with a specific meaning.

But now it's not clear to me how to achieve two goals :

- i would like to "tag" the Dto to make explicitly clear that the Dto can be used in some functionality (eg : as in the previous example that the Dto can be in some way stored)
- i would like to make it clear and "incapsulated" the logic that will handle the Dto functionality (the way to store the Dto)

Optionally i would like to achieve the goals above in the simplest way without too complex artchitecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i have the feeling this is not the correct way to proceede, Dtos (as name imply) shuld carry only information and no business logic

yeah, you are absolutely right.

> In particular i would like to add update logic to those Dtos

Logic should be placed in services if you use service layer architecture. [Ultimately, in any architecture you choose, there is going to be some component or layer that has most of the business logic.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/218394/202970) Read this beautiful answer about where your logic should be placed.

Comment: i have already implemented a business layer where i define logic (BL rely over a DAL where repository define how to udpate thing); in that sense my acutal architecture fit the first point in the list you linked to me. So if i well understand, in that scenario every time i use (in BL) a DTO that contain ContactDto (PersonDto for example) for an operation that change data, i have to "remember" to call the right ContactRepository update logic. There is no way to encapsulate this any further, right?

Comment: @Skary yeah, you are right. If you are using Service layer architecture, then you need to call a corresponding repository. In your case, it is `ContactRepository`

Comment: Ok thanks, i hoped i can be a bit more concise, but anyway is not a big deal to repeat a bit. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Skary I am glad that it helped to you! :)